# How to show values above bars in a dojox columns chart

Tags: charts, dojo

Is there any way to show the y-value of every bar above the actual bar in a dojox columns-type chart? Here's my code (which I got from http://glenurban.me.uk/A55D03/Blog.nsf/dx/DojoChart.htm):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");

var series1 = [ 3, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4]; 
var xlabels = [ 
    {value : 1, text : "a"}, 
    {value : 2, text : "b"}, 
    {value : 3, text : "c"}, 
    {value : 4, text : "d"}, 
    {value : 5, text : "e"}, 
    {value : 6, text : "f"}, 
    {value : 7, text : "g"}];

var chart1;
makeCharts = function() {
    chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart");
    chart1.addPlot("default", {
        type : "Columns",
        gap : 2
    });
    chart1.addAxis("x", {
        labels : xlabels
    });
    chart1.addAxis("y", {
        vertical : true,
        min : 0
    });
    chart1.addSeries("Series1", series1);
    chart1.render();
};

dojo.addOnLoad(makeCharts);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is a feature that still hasn't been included into the later versions of Dojo: see [ticket](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/13403), and this [ticket](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11366) (found from [this mailing list](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2011-November/060274.html).)

I've tried checking to see if there is a way to use Dojo GFX to get the values from your series of data... and then overlay that on to the chart.  But, doing labels that way is going to be kludgy *(and this all depends on if Dojo GFX's surface allows for a surface overlay on a SVG chart object already created.)*

There's always the option to add this functionality in to the Dojo Chart2D library itself.  But whenever you do that, unless you are able to get your patches changed with the main Dojo Chart2D branch, you'll want to be careful not to overwrite your custom-made library with a newer version of Chart2D in the future.

*However*, if you aren't stuck to Dojo for this particular need, have you considered using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?  There are many different chart/graph libraries out there, these days:

1. [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) ([examples](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic))
2. [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) ([examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/annotating.html))
3. [Tuftegraph](http://xaviershay.github.com/tufte-graph/index.html) ([examples](http://xaviershay.github.com/tufte-graph/test/integration.html))

Also, [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) is pretty nice, if jQuery isn't your thing.

Or... [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/demos/) is great, as well.

Comment: We're evaluating dojox and this is one of the issues that will determine whether or not we will choose it.

Comment: Dojo has a lot of great tools... but looking at its developmental pace (according to the http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org tracker,) there might be some features (like the column chart values feature you asked about,) that just won't end up being added for quite some time.  I still would recommend jQuery (and jQuery plugins,) for a general-purpose Javascript toolbox.  I guess it depends, too, on what other issues on which you are evaluating Dojo.

Comment: Just added a reference to another great Javascript library (http://thejit.org/demos/) that might be helpful, if you are still looking for a solution to your problem...

Answer (score 0):

For information, it's now possible to have columns chart with label. For exemple :

addPlot("default", {type: "ClusteredColumns", **labels: true**,labelStyle:"outside"  or "inside"  })