# How to show values above bars in a dojox columns chart (ONLY FOR BARS with height > 0)

Tags: charts, dojo, bar-chart

In this link i found a way to display values for bars.
[How to show values above bars in a dojox columns chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923891/how-to-show-values-above-bars-in-a-dojox-columns-chart)

sadly, a row of zeros plague the chart. I want to show values above the bars only when they are > 0.

Graphically, this is what dojo does:

```
       |
       |                       3   
       |                       _   
       |           1          | |  
y-axis |           _          | |
       |   0   0  | |  0   0  | |
       ----------------------------
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6      
                x-axis
```

and this is what i want to do:

```
       |
       |                       3   
       |                       _   
       |           1          | |  
y-axis |           _          | |
       |          | |         | |
       ----------------------------
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6      
                x-axis
```

Or, any other free js lib i can use? i am not particularly fond of dojo

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to patch the dojo code for this:

```
  (function() {
     var origCreateLabel =dojox.charting.plot2d.Columns.prototype.createLabel;
     dojox.charting.plot2d.Columns.prototype.createLabel = function(group, value, bbox, theme) {
    if(isNaN(value)){
        origCreateLabel.apply(this,arguments);
    }else if(value > 0){
        origCreateLabel.apply(this,arguments);
    }

    };
  })();
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/xnyne77a/